# Qt modal QDialog with Qt::CustomizeWindowHint display wrong on Windows

Tags: windows, qt

I have a Qt dialog application, both with Qt::CustomizeWindowHint flag on. In this case, QMainWindow on maximize overrides task bar.  The call of QDialog doesn't lead to anything. Why?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
    showMaximized();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    TestDialog dlg(this);
    dlg.exec();
}


TestDialog::TestDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    CustomQDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TestDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
}

TestDialog::~TestDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Example project: http://rghost.ru/41171471